# Unit testing with postgis 1.5 and django

Tags: postgis, geodjango, extensions

I'm trying to get some unit tests working in Django/PostGis. When the test database is formed, it doesn't have the postgis and postgis_topology extensions installed. Is there a way to issue commands to the database before the creation of tables happens? Or could you somehow mess with the postgres template to inherit from? Or something else that wouldn't require me to either hack the django code or not destroy the database? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
psql -d template_postgis2 -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

should create a new database with the PostGIS spatial tables enabled.

Be careful, too, if you are using different SRID's.

Good guidelines are on:
http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Oberoc, when you define in your settings the database engine, Django is smart enough to create the correct database type when running unit tests.

So you if you have something like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and you run your tests, Django will create a database name test_database_name, with PostGIS installed.